# If there are 2 NICs on the same machine, can a TCP client on one NIC connect to a TCP server on the other NIC?

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter, tcp

I use TUN/TAP to create a tun NIC `tun0` with IP 10.10.10.2, and I have a real NIC `eth0` with IP 202.112.34.49

Then I run a TCP client which binds its socket to 202.112.34.49 and a TCP server binding 10.10.10.2. but I can't establish a tcp connection between them.

So can a TCP client on one NIC connect to a tcp server on the other NIC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packets to local addresses will always run on the `lo` interface; they will never leave the machine. (Packets to local addresses arriving on non-lo interfaces are regarded as [martians](https://systemoverlord.com/2011/11/06/martian-packet-messages).)

In other words, your packets must get stuck on the `lo` interface somewhere, possibly due to a firewall. Check your `iptables-save` output and do a `tcpdump` on the `lo` interface for those packets to debug this issue.

Comment: ah, I got it, since the IPs are all local, the packets will be sent to `lo` but not tun0. If I use raw socket to modify the source IP to an non-local IP, for example, I use raw socket to send a packet to  the TCP server on 10.10.10.2, will the server react a TCP SYN/ACK destined to that non-local IP. Can I hook/intercept the SYN/ACK packet(including TCP/IP Header)? thanks

Comment: The packets destined to remote destinations will be sent according to the machine's routing table. You could of course use promisc mode on the network interface or set up a NAT to a local address, however you may want to take a look at something like LXC. It allows you to run two minimalistic virtual machines with separate network stacks.

Comment: no, what I want to do is: I have a tcp server listening on 10.10.10.2(that is the tun0), and I open a socket descriptor to the tun0. Then I can use the socket descriptor to write TCP SYN packet to the socket descriptor and read the responding TCP SYN/ACK packet. Is this usage correct? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "a socket descriptor to the tun0"?

Answer (score 3):

Neither the TCP client nor the TCP server are "on" any NICs. Individual interfaces are considered at layers 1 and 2 while TCP operates at layer 4. Except for very special socket options like `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, TCP endpoints are not attached to any network interface.

Your TCP server and client just happen to be bound to different local IP addresses. Connecting between them should work just fine.